# No such column 'ReportsTo' on entity 'Contact'

Tags: apex, soql, contact

How can i get the ReportsTo field in Contact Record in Apex? When i run the query below i get the error

> No such column 'ReportsTo' on entity 'Contact'.

```
contacts = [SELECT id, name,email,Title,ReportsTo,ReportsTo.name,ReportsTo.Title FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: Acctid];
```

OR

```
contacts = [SELECT id, name,email,Title,ReportsTo FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: Acctid];
```

Both throws the error

Any thoughts what could be the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The field name is `ReportsToId`, which you can see for yourself in the `SOAP API Developer Guide` page for the [`Contact`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) object.